# Cross-browser checking on file size at client side before uploading it to the server?

Tags: asp.net, validation, file-upload, cross-browser, client

Client side validation is important to improve usability.

Is there any cross-browser way to validate the file size before uploading it to the server. I am using asp.net file upload control.

I found some third-party controls do that check:

http://ajaxuploader.com/Demo/simple-upload.aspx

and

http://demo.essentialobjects.com/Default.aspx?path=AJAXU

but How?

Comment: The controls you found all use flash:) look at the js. They embed swf files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Previously, the only way to determine the filesize before the file was sent over to the server was to have 'thicker than javascript' client-side plugins/add-ons. These would have to be installed on the client system. E.g. using SWFUpload, Java applets, ActiveX controls.

Now, you can use the HTML5 File API, i.e.:

```
var size = document.getElementById('myfile').files[0].size;
```

Comment: looks like a copy of my answer!

Comment: @redsquare, I added your "swfupload" as one of the examples. A +1 for that. :-)

Comment: True when it was written, no longer true with the HTML5 File API.

Comment: Added a HTML5 File Api example :)

Answer (score 4):

This is now possible with HTML5's File API:

```
<script>
    var myFile = document.getElementById('myFile');
    var size;
    myFile.addEventListener('change', function() {
        size = this.files[0].size;
    });
</script>
```

This is supported by [most of the latest browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi).

Internet Explorer supports [this workaround](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/01/check-for-file-size-with-javascript-before-uploading.html) involving ActiveX, but it requires lowering Internet Explorer's security settings, so it isn't really an option for most applications.

It takes more work, but use a Flash-based uploader such as [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org) if you really need to do this in IE9 or below. IE10 will (hopefully) add support for the HTML5 File API.

Comment: The IE workaround can be summarized as: "Turn off all security and get PC owned instantly.) 

IE10 offers HTML5 File API.