# Programmatically Determine Exchange Attachment Limit

Tags: email, attachment, exchange-server

Is there any way to query the exchange server to determine the maximum attachment file size?  I'd be doing this in ASP.NET/C#.  I'd like to be able to validate the file they want to attach is not over the limit before the user attempts to send the file to the server as opposed to having the server send back an exception when it attempts to attach the file and it discovers the file is too large.

Answer (score 0):

I think my question was a bad question.  After thinking it through, I realized that would involve the browser being able to determine the file size client side.  That rang a bell from a long time ago and based on [Cross-browser checking on file size at client side before uploading it to the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250414/cross-browser-checking-on-file-size-at-client-side-before-uploading-it-to-the-ser), it's not possible - at least not in a way that I can implement.

Comment: Just realized that my question isn't a bad one in and of itself, but it is based on what I want to do (get file size client side).  But the question itself might be useful to others - say someone writing a Windows app.