# How to put file upload limit in gwt client side?

Tags: java, gwt

I want to make validation not to upload a file more than 100 MB in my file up loader widget.
Currently I am uploading the file and transferring it on server side and there on server side checking the size.
Is there any way so that I can check the file size on client side itself so that it will reduce the time
required for file transfer to server side

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript file upload size validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717793/javascript-file-upload-size-validation)

Comment: check size during upload? You could cut it if it goes over 100mb

Comment: As I write in other question, you can try this:


[http://stackoverflow.com/a/31473567/4021734][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31473567/4021734

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, because `javascript` doesn't provide any way to read the contents of a `file` that is stored locally.

You have to do it on server side. And its always a better option to validate on server side

Comment: @kedar IMHO No.You have to do it on serverside only .And do not depend on client validation.It can easily by passed.

Comment: @johnchen902 java is tagged because,gwt can code in java and compiles to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [W3C Files API](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/). There is a GWT wrapper for it at http://www.vectomatic.org/libs/lib-gwt-file.