# GWT Image Upload empty content

Tags: file-upload, gwt, image-uploading, image-upload

I am trying to implement GWT image upload functionality. I have made the required code change but for some reason upload is not happening. At the server side the image is not being received. So I checked at the client side (browser) the request header and content and then I found that Content-Length: 44 (just 44). Then I realized that the image is not being sent to server on from submission. Please check the below GWT code.

```
    VerticalPanel vp = new VerticalPanel();
    vp.add(CommonFormLayoutUtil.createLabel("Upload"));
    final FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
    form.setAction("CGIImageUpload");
    // set form to use the POST method, and multipart MIME encoding.
    form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
    form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);

    final FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();
    Button uploadButton = new Button("Upload");
    uploadButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            //get the filename to be uploaded
            String filename = fileUpload.getFilename();
            if (filename.length() == 0) {
                showError("No File Specified!", null);
            } else {
                //submit the form
                form.submit();                    
            }               
        }
    });
    vp.add(fileUpload);
    vp.add(uploadButton);

    form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
            // When the form submission is successfully completed, this 
            //event is fired. Assuming the service returned a response 
            //of type text/html, we can get the result text here 
            showError(event.getResults(), null);        
        }
    });
    form.add(vp);
```

Am i missing anything here? Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FormPanel states the following:

"This panel can be used to achieve interoperability with servers that accept traditional HTML form encoding. The following widgets (**those that implement com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HasName**) will be submitted to the server if they are contained within this panel" (emphasis mine)

You need to set the name of the FileUpload widget otherwise it will not be submitted by the FormPanel.

```
fileUpload.setName("someName");
```

Try setting this and it should work

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, your answer is correct. All the examples on internet doesn't provide name attribute, this misled me actually.  Anyways Thanks once again.

Comment: I need some help on the features available in GWT FileUpload. 1. is it possible to get the size of an image . 2. Is it possible to get pixel size of an image.

Comment: Do you mean on the client side before uploading the file or on the server side?

Comment: client side before uploading the file. Sorry for not being specific.

Comment: This might be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883231/check-file-size-before-upload-using-gwt. Any particular reason you can't control those things on the server side and let the client know?

Comment: For server side validation we need to have the images uploaded to server and if some size validation fails then we will discard that image. if we can validate at the client layer itself then it reduces unnecessary burden to server. One more question, Is there any can we can upload image using AJAX in GWT? or can we send images/files in Base64 fromat using XML in GWT?

Comment: I would recommend adding the validation to the server either way.. client-side validation can be circumvented and shouldn't be relied upon. As for your other question I don't know of such a way off the top of my head, you will have to do some research or post a new question I think.